# How to merge .config and .msi file in single exe

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows-installer, exe

I have a `.config` and `.msi` file and I want to convert it to the single `EXE` setup file. since I do not have a source code of this file. how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the .config is part of the MSI,  I'd first use ORCA to create a transform that disables it from the MSI.  Then I'd use Windows Installer XML (WiX) to create an MSI that contains only the .config. Finally I'd use WiX to create a Burn bootstrapper the installs the MSI (applying the transform) and then installs the config MSI.  It would all show up in Programs and Features as a single entry controlled by the bootstrapper.

Comment: I looking to create exe setup file

Comment: And that's what you would haven  A single EXE that extracts and installs 2 MSI under the covers.